# How to capture audio signal from an instrument connected to the 3.5mm audio jack via 1/4" cable in Android?

Tags: android, audio, android-audiomanager

I'm experimenting with connecting my guitar to my Nexus 5, how can I capture the audio signals from my guitar pickups through the 1/4" audio cable connecting my guitar to the 3.5mm audio jack?

Comment: `AudioRecord` is probably one option.

Comment: do you interested in analyzing wave spectrum ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an adapter that will convert the signal coming from the guitar to the signal used by your phone.

One such device is made by Peavy:

http://www.musiciansfriend.com/pro-audio/peavey-ampkit-link-guitar-interface-for-iphone-and-ipod-touch

It claims to be for iPod Touch and iPhone but the jack is standard and the same on Android phones including your Nexus 5.

Answer (score 0):

Your Nexus 5 have only 3.5 audioout, there is no jack to connect the external microfone.
To use the buildin mic you should use as mentioned by @CommonsWare the android.media.AudioRecord class.
The easiest code sample is [here](https://github.com/liwenhaosuper/SysOfIMPS/blob/6c52fb96c24b0dffb194a5c784b0d50044ad0033/IMPS/src/com/imps/audio/Record.java)

Comment: The headset jack has both input and output on the same jack to allow you to use a headset with a microphone with your phone. If you look closely at a headset with microphone plug it has 4 rings instead of the 3 needed for a stereo headset. One is ground, one is left out, one is right out, and one is mic in.

Comment: Yes, you've provided a great device, a how i've fogrot about headset :( But anyway after connecting your device the author must use AudioRecord class to record the signal.